# Open a page only if it is referred by Own website

Tags: php, html

Is there a way so that a particular page is opened only if it is referred from somewhere on the same website and does not opens if direct URL is entered? I want the results page of my Quiz website to work this way. Any help? Please ask for any more details or explanations needed. I would prefer the functionality in php.

Comment: Why not just set a session token while playing the quiz and make the results page depend on verifying that token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`. However, you certainly can't rely on it as it can be easily spoofed. The best option is to set a session variable on page A, which they will need in order to access page B. Very basic example:

**page-a.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['page_a_visited'] = true;
//Display HTML and link to page-b.php, etc.
```

**page-b.php**

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_a_visited'])){
    //Directly accessing the page without having visited Page A.
    //Or session has expired.
    exit;
}
```

In response to your comment. If your quiz needs to force the user to navigate from Question 1 through to Question 10:

Instead of `$_SESSION['page_a_visited'] = true;`, use something like `$_SESSION['page_a_visited'] = $questionId;` When they're on Question 2, make sure that `$_SESSION['page_a_visited']` exists and that it is equal to 1. When they're on Question 3, make sure that `$_SESSION['page_a_visited']` exists and that it is equal to 2. And so on.

Comment: Let me explain it a bit more. The are 10 questions in each of my qui. All of the 10 questions are served one after the other dynamically from  the databas. So  if I say the session in the code for my quiz, the session will be set after the very first question and the results page could still be accessed by directly ending the URL and a wrong result will be displayed as the result depends on another session variable which holds the temporary score

Comment: @user2801699 Instead of `$_SESSION['page_a_visited'] = true;`, use something like `$_SESSION['page_a_visited'] = $questionId;` When they're on Question 2, make sure that `$_SESSION['page_a_visited']` exists and that it is equal to 1. When they're on Question 3, make sure that `$_SESSION['page_a_visited']` exists and that it is equal to 2. And so on.

Comment: That satisfies my question. Thank you. Please add this to the answer so that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This function checks if the page referring to your page is in the same "directory" and server space. I used it in my own work, maybe you get some ideas if it is not applicable directly as is.

```
function external_referral()
{
    if( empty( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $url = parse_url( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] );

        return ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] != $url["host"] || dirname( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ) != dirname( $url["path"] ) );
    }
}
```